# How to start Docker Axon server in development mode

Tags: spring, docker, axon

I'm new to Axon and Docker and I would like to start axon server in Docker using developmnent mode in order to clear events as I'm in the process of building a system and my events and commands change often.

I read on Axon documentation that a certain property `axoniq.axonserver.devmode.enabled` (defaults to `false`) has to be set. I also know that Axon uses spring boot, so I guess I would need to somehow access the `axonserver.properties` on Docker, but here is the problem, i don't know how.

I would be thankful if anyone could explain how to change this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunatelly Axon has been publishing blogs about running axon-server and one of them, they teach how to run it on docker =)

Blog post:  https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/running-axon-server-in-docker

The important part, in your case, is here:

> A third directory, not marked as a volume in the image, is important for our case: If you put an “axonserver.properties” file in “/config”, it can override the settings above and add new ones:

Which means, you can create your `axonserver.properties` in this directory with the desired property (`axoniq.axonserver.devmode.enabled=true`) and it will pick it up from there!

On the other hand, you can also set the environment variable: `AXONIQ_AXONSERVER_DEVMODE_ENABLED` to `true`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: By environmental variable you mean in my os or on docker?

Comment: Docker!  You can use `--env` or `-e` for that. The [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options) can help you!

Answer (score 0):

For windows cmd with Docker version 19.03.8

`docker run -d --rm --name axonserver -p 8024:8024 -p 8124:8124 -v <your absolute path to axonserver.properties>:/axonserver/config axoniq/axonserver:<tag of axon image>`

where absolute path is Windows-style string

unix style command line

`docker run -d --rm --name axonserver -p 8024:8024 -p 8124:8124 -v <your absolute path to axonserver.properties>:/axonserver/config axoniq/axonserver:<tag of axon image>`
where absolute path is unix-style string